# QT Creator: проблема при взаимодействии слотов и сигналов

Tags: qt, c++

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь в QT написать следующее приложение. Имеется главное окно, в котором в качестве главного виджета устанавливается виджет Меню. В нем происходит выбор, какой виджет сделать главным и нажимается соответствуюшая кнопка. Сигнал соединяю со слотом главного окна, который устанавливает в качестве нового главного окна другой виджет. На этом новом виджете есть своя кнопка, по нажатии которой по сигналу собственно в главном окне рисуется виджет меню. Проблема в том, что при нажатии этой кнопки в новом виджете программа "неожиданно завершается". Подскажите, в чем моя проблема?
Собственно Файл с классами lib.h

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
//Виджет меню
class Menu: public QWidget
{
 Q_OBJECT
 private:
    QPushButton *button1;
    QPushButton *button2;
    QPushButton *button3;
    QVBoxLayout *layout;
 public:
    Menu(QWidget *);
    ~Menu();
 signals:
    void sig_first_widget();
    void sig_second_widget();
    void sig_exit();
};
//Первый виджет
class FirstWidget: public QWidget
{
 Q_OBJECT
 private:
    QPushButton *button;
    QVBoxLayout *layout;
public:
    FirstWidget(QWidget*);
    ~FirstWidget();
signals:
    void set_menu();
};
//Второй виджет
class SecondWidget: public QWidget
{
 Q_OBJECT
 private:
    QPushButton *button;
    QVBoxLayout *layout;
 public:
    SecondWidget(QWidget*);
    ~SecondWidget();
 signals:
    void set_menu();
};
//Главное окно
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
 Q_OBJECT
private:
    Menu *menu;
    FirstWidget *first;
    SecondWidget *second;
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void set_first();
    void set_second();
    void set_menu();
};
#endif // LIB_H
```

Реализация классов и ф-ция main():

```
#include "lib.h"
//
Menu::Menu(QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent)
{
 button1 = new QPushButton("set_first_widget");
 button2 = new QPushButton("set_second_widget");
 button3 = new QPushButton("exit");
 layout = new QVBoxLayout;
 layout->addWidget(button1);
 layout->addWidget(button2);
 layout->addWidget(button3);
 this->setLayout(layout);
 connect(button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SIGNAL(sig_first_widget()));
 connect(button2, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SIGNAL(sig_second_widget()));
 connect(button3, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SIGNAL(sig_exit()));
}
//
Menu::~Menu()
{
 delete button1;
 delete button2;
 delete button3;
 delete layout;
}
//
FirstWidget::FirstWidget(QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent)
{
 button = new QPushButton("This is the first widget");
 layout = new QVBoxLayout;
 layout->addWidget(button);
 this->setLayout(layout);
 connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SIGNAL(set_menu()));
}
//
FirstWidget::~FirstWidget()
{
 delete button;
 delete layout;
}
//
SecondWidget::SecondWidget(QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent)
{
 button = new QPushButton("This is the second widget");
 layout = new QVBoxLayout;
 layout->addWidget(button);
 this->setLayout(layout);
 connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SIGNAL(set_menu()));
}
//
SecondWidget::~SecondWidget()
{
 delete button;
 delete layout;
}
//
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent)
{
 menu = new Menu(this);
 first = new FirstWidget(this);
 second = new SecondWidget(this);
 this->setCentralWidget(menu);
 connect(menu, SIGNAL(sig_exit()), this, SLOT(close()));
 connect(menu, SIGNAL(sig_first_widget()), this, SLOT(set_first()));
 connect(menu, SIGNAL(sig_second_widget()), this, SLOT(set_second()));
 connect(first, SIGNAL(set_menu()), this, SLOT(set_menu()));
 connect(second, SIGNAL(set_menu()), this, SLOT(set_menu()));
}
//
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
 delete menu;
 delete first;
 delete second;
}
//
void MainWindow::set_first()
{
 this->setCentralWidget(first);
}
//
void MainWindow::set_second()
{
 this->setCentralWidget(second);
}
//
void MainWindow::set_menu()
{
 this->setCentralWidget(menu);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QApplication a(argc, argv);
 MainWindow *w = new MainWindow(0);
 w->show();
 return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Документация по setCentralWidget говорит:

```
void QMainWindow::setCentralWidget ( QWidget * widget )
Sets the given widget to be the main window's central widget.

Note: QMainWindow takes ownership of the widget pointer and deletes it at the appropriate time.
```

Обратите внимание на замечание. CentralWidget - не обычный контейнер, заместив его содержимое другим виджетом, вы уничтожаете исходный. Это хорошо видно в отладчике. При вызове `this->setCentralWidget(first);` вы первым делом попадаете в деструктор класса Menu.

Менять содержимое CentralWidget - не очень хорошая практика.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что для вашей задачи подойдет такой подход:
 - создаете свой класс CentralWidget, наследник от QWidget
 - устанавливаете ему QStackedLayout
 - помещаете в этот layout все виждеты которые вам нужны и связываете действия меню со слотом который выглядит примерно так:

```
void chooseWidget()
{
  QStackedLayout *sl = qobject_cast<QStackedLayout*>(centranWidget().layout());
  sl->setCurrentWidget(...)
}
```

Естественно, я опустил проверку ошибок